# Asymptotic Relationship between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

What is the asymptotic relationship between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{2^n}$?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798974/function-which-is-big-o1-but-not-%CE%A91) mentions that both functions are $O(1)$ (because they are always $\leq 1$) but not $\Omega(1)$ (because the functions will not be always greater than any constant $c>0$, as both are eventually 0).

Thinking of it using limits: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\tfrac{1}{n}}{\tfrac{1}{2^n}}=\infty$, which implies that $\frac{1}{2^n}=o(\frac{1}{n})$. However, both functions are decreasing (not increasing) and both eventually meet at zero. I.e. no function will always be greater than the other. So I can't wrap my head around it!

I assume this question applies in general to other decreasing functions as well (e.g. $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$).

Comment: "no function will always be greater than the other": this is wrong, the functions never meet (infinity does not count). For all naturals, $\frac1n>\frac1{2^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in concluding it is $O(1)$ and not $\Omega(1)$ (talking purely about functions). However saying its $O(1)$ because they are always $\leq 1$ is slightly incorrect as it can be seen from the graph below. Since these functions are in the denominator they would approach $0$ very fast. In asymptotic analysis, $n \to \infty $ means ***for sufficiently large value of*** $n$, and it can be seen from the graph that even a small value$(n=1)$ is enough to show the asymptotic relationships between the functions.

The graph of $\frac{1}{n}$(green curve) approaches zero slower than that for  $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (violet/purple curve). Clearly, $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is upper bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$ i.e.  $\frac{1}{2^n} = O(\frac{1}{n})$ and as you yourself have mentioned in the question $\frac{1}{2^n}=o(\frac{1}{n})$.

Even by using the standard definition of Big-O

for $$\frac{1}{2^n} = O(\frac{1}{n})$$ we need to show

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\leq c\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$ for some positive constant $c$. Putting $c=1$ the equation holds true for all values of $n>0$. Similarly you can figure out the asymptotic relationships for other decreasing functions as well.

[image: asymptotics of functions]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what their asymptotic relationship is. Is it true that $\frac{1}{2^n} = O(\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just like $n=O(2^n)$ (the exponential grows much much faster), $\dfrac1n=\Omega\left(\dfrac1{2^n}\right)$.